# What is the recommended class for making Q&A document?

Tags: packages, document-classes

I want to make a help guide for Game Theory students where the document contains question and answer. For example-

> 1.**What is a unique Nash equilibrium?**
>   A Nash Equilibrium is a set of strategies that players act out, with the property that no player benefits from changing their strategy. ... For example, in the game of trying to guess 2/3 of the average guesses, the unique Nash equilibrium is (counterintuitively) for all players to choose 0.
>   2. **How is Nash equilibrium different from dominant strategy?**
>   A (pure strategy) nash equilibrium can still involve strategies that are weakly dominated. ... On the other hand, a dominant strategy equilibrium is when all players play a strictly dominant strategy. A nash equilibrium does not imply that both players always play a strictly dominant strategy.

This is not a hard orientation. You can also suggest a better orientation. But each question is followed by a answer.

Using the `exam` package

```
%author Md. Al-Helal
%date April 3, 2019
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{exam}
%\usepackage{amsmath,multirow,booktabs,fullpage,tabularx,graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\author{Md. Al-Helal}
\title{Game Theory Note}
\printanswers
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{questions}
\question Can there be a Nash equilibrium without a dominant strategy?
\begin{solution}
Dominant strategies are considered as better than other strategies, no matter what other players might do. In game theory, there are two kinds of strategic dominance: ... It must be noted that any dominant strategy equilibrium is always a Nash equilibrium. However, not all Nash equilibria are dominant strategy equilibria
\end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This can be done manually (making a list). But, I want to know is their any default class or package for this type of job?

Thank you.

Comment: Try exam package: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam

Comment: I think basic ones like `article` is enough. You only have to define more commands and environments.

Comment: @nidhin Is `ans` package related to this job?

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: @alhelal I don’t know about ans package.